# CSRF token was not automatically added as hidden parameter

Tags: hdiv

Trying a sample application integrating HDIV with Spring Security CSRF and facing a problem - CSRF token is not automatically added as hidden parameter to the generated form.

The configuration in Spring security-config.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    ...
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>
```

But when we explicitly add the following line to the form, CSRF validation works.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

The version details:

- HDIV : 2.1.9
- Spring : 3.2.13 (Also tried with 4.0.5.RELEASE)
- Spring Security: 3.2.6.RELEASE (Also tried with 3.2.4.RELEASE)

Appreciate any clues/inputs..

Answer (score 0):

My bad, was using html form instead of Spring form. 
Once changed to Spring `<form:form`, it's working fine.